# Understanding what might trigger Laravel configs to be cached (aside from the artisan command)

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to better understand how the Laravel 5.6 system for caching configs work.

I understand that running `php artisan config:cache` will generate a cache file of configs and `php artisan config:clear` will clear this cache.

**My question is what (if anything) might trigger the config cache to be created when it's not manually done so via one of the above commands?**

I teach a college course that uses Laravel, and I'm seeing students hitting a wall when they update their .env files but don't see the changes reflected in the app. It happens randomly - not for every student - and I've only seen it happen once on my end. I'm unable to purposefully recreate it.

Of course, running `php artisan config:clear` resolves the problem - but I'd like to better understand what might be triggering the cache "under the hood".

Comment: Can you describe the development environment that's being used? Are you using `php artisan serve`?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy MAMP on Mac